# How can I combine these two regexes?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to combine the following two regexes into one:

- `^([A-Z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})$` e.g. AB 1234
- `^([0-9]{1,4}) ?([A-Z]{1,2})$` e.g. 1234 AB

I thought this would be a simple as this:

`^([A-Z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,4}) ?([A-Z]{1,2})$`

However, the above always returns 4 groups, e.g.

1. `''`
2. `''`
3. `'1234'`
4. `'AB'`

How can I combine these two regexes in a way that will always returns two groups? e.g.

1. `'1234'`
2. `'AB'`

or

1. `'AB'`
2. `'1234'`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?  What's the benefit?  It will certainly not result in something easier to read.

Comment: I need to match a string, which is in one of a number of predefined formats. All of the formats result in two groups being returned, so I would like to do this using a single regex rather than performing a number of individual matches.

Comment: Why do you think that one match is better than two?

Comment: for us to help you better, put the full string in the question, and then how you want it to look afterwards, example: `s = "Hello World!"` and the regex should extract: `['Hello', 'World']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your combination is not quite right, because the `^` only applies to the first alternative and the `$` only applies to the second one. So you need to group the alternation:

```
^(?:([A-Z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,4}) ?([A-Z]{1,2}))$
```

Now what you want to achieve can not be done with all regex engines, but some (e.g. PCRE) support a special alternation construct where capturing groups are counted individually for all alternations. This is the syntax:

```
^(?|([A-Z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,4}) ?([A-Z]{1,2}))$
```

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, this is in particular not supported by Python. Neither is the alternative of reusing a named capturing group. Hence you will probably have to filter empty strings out of `match.groups()` or stick to two regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks. What is the `?|` construct called? Python doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: @gjb I have no idea what it's called. You might be able to accomplish the same thing with named capturing groups, I'm trying it out right now

Comment: @gjb no unfortunately not, named groups cannot be reused in python. I think in that case it is not possible to get exactly the result you want. But you could simply filter out empty results from the `match.groups()`.